# C# Read specific text from text file

Tags: c#

I have text file with questions and answers.I want to take all question from file.How to read all text from file that starts with **`"`** and ends with `?`

Comment: Hint: ReadAllLines from file to a list, filter the list by checking `StartsWith()` and `EndsWith()` required list is ready

Answer (score 2):

It can be :

```
string s = "\" Is this sample question ?";
int start = s.IndexOf("\"") + 1;
int end = s.IndexOf("?", start);
string result = s.Substring(start, end - start);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like This:

```
List<string> questions = System.IO.File.ReadLines("path here")
                                       .Where(x => x.StartsWith("\"") &&
                                                   x.EndsWith("?"))
                                       .ToList();
```

To add them to the ListBox you can use the following code:

```
foreach(string x in questions)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(x)
}
```

Comment: I am trying to print all text from question list to listBox but it's not working: List<string> questions = File.ReadLines(path)
                                       .Where(x => x.StartsWith("\"") &&
                                                   x.EndsWith("?"))
                                       .ToList();
            foreach(var x in questions)
            listBox1.Text = questions.ToString();

Comment: The name x does not exist in current context: foreach (var listBox1.Items.Add(x) in questions)
            listBox1.Text = questions.ToString();

Comment: see the updates

Comment: I addes this but nothing happens when I click button: foreach(string x in questions)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(x)
}